# Looking for documentation about Lowcoder/Openblocks-plugins functions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, documentation

My request is about the creation of a plugin for OB/Lowcoder. I'm trying to create a plugin to manage the authentication of the users of an OB/Lowcoder application. I am a beginner in development and on top of that, I can't find any documentation about the various functions that can be used with openblocks-plugins, so I'm a bit stuck. <kbd>F12</kbd> in VSCode makes me arrive on the `app-env.d.ts` file.

I already know this page : [openblocks-plugin](https://docs.openblocks.dev/build-plugins/develop-your-first-plugin). I'm registered on the Discord Openblocks server as well as on the new server dedicated to Lowcoder.

Does anyone have any information that could help me, please? Here are some more specific questions:

- Is there any documentation about the functions that can be used like in the example (antd, UICompBuilder, numberExposingStateControl, Section, withDefault, withExposingConfigs, NumberControl, NameConfig, eventHandlerControl, withMethodExposing...)?
- What are these functions for?
- What are they waiting for as parameters?
- What are their return type?
- What are all the functions that exist?
- Is there a particular way to handle the integration of my own source code in what I call the "plugin factory"?
- Do you know a tutorial about OB plugin creation? (so far I found little information about this tool, but a lot about an extension for *Minecraft*...)

Answer (score -1):

We made progress to collect more information about the SDK finally. We know, the List is not complete, neither can we be 100% sure about the exact functions at all components, as Lowcoder continued the Project, which was Openblocks before.

https://docs.lowcoder.cloud/lowcoder-documentation/lowcoder-extension/native-embed-sdk

We still think this list is already truly helpful. Also, as it is a fundament regarding the Plugin Builder for visual Components.

https://github.com/lowcoder-org/lowcoder-create-component-plugin